# What is required to send messages via USSD?

Tags: sms, payment, ussd

I'm trying to get started with **USSD**. I'm familiar with other *forms of SMS*.
Ultimately i want to use **USSD** as part of a real-time payment platform.

Thanks.

Comment: There is plug-in for [new Symbian phones](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Phone_Client_USSD_API) (3rd edition FP2)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here are some of the questions you'd like to find answers for as you proceed with your USSD plan.

•. How do we want the channel to work?

For starters, USSD is just like connection-oriented SMS communication i.e, USSD is to SMS what IM is to email. The initiation of the communication can either be USSD-PUSH ( Mobile-terminated & provider originated) or a USSD-PULL (Mobile originated & provider terminated). In your case, I believe it would probably be a mobile originated USSD pull where the mobile subscriber dials a USSD short code on his mobile to access the app.

•. If it is USSD-PULL... what is our short code?

Every app requires a separate short code. USSD shortcodes are site addresses scheme similar to the website addresses in the internet world. I am not sure what country you are from, but here in India, USSD shortcodes are owned by the mobile service providers and one needs to get the service provider to configure the right short codes for you.

•. Now, what is the communication interface?

USSD works using a connection oriented SMPP. However, USSD gateways ( service-provider owned middle-ware that relays USSD messages to and from the subscribers' mobiles, these days are capable of acting as bridges where their app interface can be over HTTP or HTTPS. In this case, I'd think you'd need HTTP or HTTPS connectivity opened between the mobile operator's gateway and your app. From then on, it is just matter of building a web-app with a text response!

Comment: Thanks for the very informative response
i guess the next step is to aquire a network shortcode and setup a htp service to act as a bridge like you suggested.

What forms of applications have you been able to develop using this technology?

thanks.

Comment: can you give references to more technical details like headers

Comment: Its a good Answer, now how to implement a USSD push using rails app?

Answer (score 6):

[Vumi](http://vumi.org) is the name of a free opensource server that runs USSD app's for you.

Indeed, you need to know which country you want the USSD code to work and have partnerships with those networks or someone who is already partnered with those networks.
e.g. in South Africa you could use [TruTeq](http://www.truteq.co.za) for example. Or [Vodacom Messaging](http://www.vodacommessaging.co.za).

Answer (score 5):

I just found out that [Mobicents](http://www.mobicents.org/index.html) has a ussd gateway and simulator . all you need to do is to checkout their source code from their SVN and "mvn clean install" the files. I didn't try it yet . But I know mobicent is a reliable program.

- this is their [introduction to USSD](http://www.mobicents.org/incubator/ussd/intro.html)
- this is their [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mobicents-public)
- A thread on how to [install ussd gateway](http://groups.google.com/group/mobicents-public/browse_thread/thread/b72d676a42c7e852/291e90d99f7bad02?lnk=gst&q=ussd#291e90d99f7bad02)

Answer (score 3):

I just Googled around and gathered info.

According to [Unstructured Supplementary Services Data (USSD)](http://www.telecomspace.com/messaging-ussd.html):

> Unstructured Supplementary Services
>   Data (USSD) allows for the
>   transmission of information via a GSM
>   network. Contrasting with SMS, it
>   offers real time connection during a
>   session. A USSD message can be upto
>   182 alphanumeric characters in length.
>   Unstructured Supplementary Service
>   Data allows interactive services
>   between a MS and applications hosted
>   by the Mobile Operator. These messages
>   are composed of digits and the #, *
>   keys, and allow users to easily and
>   quickly get information/access
>   services from the Operator.
>
> USSD messages are simple to form and
>   easy to send. User can directly enter
>   the ussd string and press call to send
>   the message. A typical USSD message
>   starts with a * followed by digits
>   which indicate an action to be
>   performed or are parameters. Each
>   group of numbers is separated by a *,
>   and the message is terminated with a #.
>   The USSD gateway in turn can interact with external applications
>   based on the USSD command. This allows
>   access to number of value added
>   services via USSD.

- USSD works on all GSM handsets of Phase II or later.

However, if you are writing [Java MIDlet on a Nokia device, it does not work](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=145899).