# How to send a USSD Code to mobile phones

Tags: sms, ussd

I want to send and run a USSD code on mobile phones via PHP. I have an SMS gateway, can I send it through SMS or do I need to purchase an other service? I have been searching the net and didn't come to a solution that's perfect for me.

Some company's support told me that I can send it using XML in SMS.

The USSD command I want to run is :

```
    1. *21*___SOME NO____#
    2. #21#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USSD and SMS are two different services that are both supported in 3gpp mobile protocols.
Check your documentation, or ask a support engineer at the organisation that supplies your SMS gateway to know if they also support USSD.  If yes, then they should give you details on how to use it.

The interface to a USSD gateway is not standard, it will depend on how the individual company has implemented it.

A quick search on Google for the words "ussd gateway" brings up several USSD products.

Comment: What I find on searching USSD Gateway is a package that allows me to create a USSD Application in which a user runs a USSD code on his mobile and then there is a response accordingly.

But what I want actually is to run a USSD code on the mobile automatically, i.e. the user does not initiate it or in other words it runs automatically on the device.

Comment: If you mean that you want the mobile to intiate a USSD dialogue automatically, then you would need some software on the mobile to do that via USSD-PULL.  If you mean that you want to initiate an action from the network on the device via a USSD message from the network, then you need USSD-PUSH.  Maybe you have already seen this question, it adds some relevant info as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347465/what-is-required-to-send-messages-via-ussd